# why play framework project in intellij taking too much time to load in browser

Tags: browser, intellij-idea, load, playframework-2.2, slowdown

I have a play framework project in my Intellij IDE when I reload page in browser Its takes 6 minutes to completely reload page in browser and in my console it starts the server and stops it and so on for six minutes

My Console ouput

```
--- (RELOAD) ---

INFO  - Shutting down connection pool...
DEBUG - Terminating pool watch thread
INFO  - Connection pool has been shutdown.
DEBUG - Connection pool has been shut down
INFO  - datasource [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/portaljob] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
DEBUG - JDBC URL = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/portaljob, Username = postgres, partitions = 1, max (per partition) = 30, min (per partition) = 5, idle max age = 10 min, idle test period = 1 min, strategy = DEFAULT
INFO  - database [default] connected at jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/portaljob
DEBUG - select relname from pg_class where relkind='S'
INFO  - Application started (Dev)
[info] Compiling 2 Java sources to E:\Software\intellij_worksapce\PortalJob\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[info] Compiling 2 Java sources to E:\Software\intellij_worksapce\PortalJob\target\scala-2.10\classes...

--- (RELOAD) ---

INFO  - Shutting down connection pool...
DEBUG - Terminating pool watch thread
INFO  - Connection pool has been shutdown.
DEBUG - Connection pool has been shut down
INFO  - datasource [jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/portaljob] bound to JNDI as DefaultDS
DEBUG - JDBC URL = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/portaljob, Username = postgres, partitions = 1, max (per partition) = 30, min (per partition) = 5, idle max age = 10 min, idle test period = 1 min, strategy = DEFAULT
INFO  - database [default] connected at jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/portaljob
DEBUG - select relname from pg_class where relkind='S'
INFO  - Application started (Dev)
[info] Compiling 2 Java sources to E:\Software\intellij_worksapce\PortalJob\target\scala-2.10\classes...
[info] Compiling 2 Java sources to E:\Software\intellij_worksapce\PortalJob\target\scala-2.10\classes...
```

and above is shown in my console for until six minutes

Is it normal?
What could be the reason for that and how can I solve this??

Note:I am working in localhost

Thanks

Comment: Yes, that's normal the play app is restarted, NO this is definitely not normal, that it takes 6 minutes, should be done in max several seconds (depending on your machine's performance). Use browser's inspection tool and in Network tab check what is loading so long, maybe some file from external CDN ?

Comment: @biesior this only happens when I run my app through intellij and if I run my app through terminal it loads perfectly in less time,what could be the reason for that?

Comment: Do you run through Menu > Run > Run/Debug command ? In such case in your config remove the `Make` step - btw most probably on the bottom of IDE there's small progress bar which shows what's happening, check what's this and try to avoid it

Comment: @biesior I removed the make option in configuration but still same issue

Comment: @biesior I have to restart my IDE to effect the changes told by you,now page is taking less time to load.Can You post your comment as an answer so that it would be helpful for other stack user and I can mark It as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was running my application through `Menu > Run > Run/Debug` so I removed `Make` step from the configuration and now its taking less time to run .

Thanks to @biesior