# IntelliJ IDEA + Play Framework - how to speed up compilation

Tags: java, intellij-idea, playframework-2.0

We just started using Play Framework 2 (Java) with IntelliJ IDEA (14.1.1) on a new project.

As it is now, simple tasks like running tests always seem to start with a 20 second long "make" step, and then the tests itself takes a few milliseconds.

According to the "messages" view, the Play 2.0 compiler is handling compilation, even though this is not checked in the Play2 options in IDEA.

Is this normal?

Are there any known quickfixes for how to make this work in a practical way?

Comment: did you try [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27795764/why-play-framework-project-in-intellij-taking-too-much-time-to-load-in-browser)

Comment: Yes, that makes things run faster, but compiling the code first is the main point of running the tests while doing test driven development. It seems to be related to an [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8183) in IDEA, where the Play Compiler is used, even though it is not selected, and this compiler spends at least 20 seconds every single time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A workaround was described in the issue mentioned in my last comment.

1. Disable play2 compiler in settings
2. Delete the play*xml files in the .idea folder for your project
3. Restart IDEA
4. If you reimport the project (e.g. when build.sbt changes), you'll have to delete the xml files and restart IDEA again.

This will presumably be fixed - look for updates in the [YouTrack Issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/SCL-8183)